# Speeding up big set of programmatically created buttons display

Tags: java, android, multithreading, programmatically-created

I have an activity which generates a scrollable list (let's say a column) of programmatically created buttons from a List which is the result of an sqlite table read and my problem is that as the List is growing (and so the number of buttons) the initial painting of the screen is becoming slow (at the moment is taking 3 seconds with 50 buttons to draw) so I'm looking for a solution to this.

At first I thought of using a thread (runnable, handler or whatever is best), let's say creating a new thread inside the For which iterates over the list but it's not working (or at least I'm not being able to make it to work) so my question is the next:

Starting from a List<> which is the most appropiate way to create a big set of scrollable buttons so users doesn't have such delay when accesing the screen.

Paginating could be an option, but I'd like to know about other possibilities first and leave that as a last resource.

Thanks, and below is my code.

```
public static void createButtons(LinearLayout llContainer,
                                     List<TestType> TestTypes, List<Test> Tests,
                                     int buttonFontSize) {

        Context oContext = llContainer.getContext();
        String strTheme = TMAppearance.getThemeFromPreferences(oContext);
        testMe = ((ApplicationConfiguration)oContext.getApplicationContext());
        int callerActivity = TestTypes!=null ? 2 : 1;

        if (TestTypes!=null || Tests!=null) {
            int lCols = strTheme.equals(testMe.theme_vivid) ? 1 : 2;

            //int sourceElementIndex = 0;
            int originListSize = calculateOriginalListSize(callerActivity, TestTypes, Tests);
            int lRows = (int) Math.ceil((double)originListSize/lCols);

            List<String> aStartColors = TMUtils_ThemeVivid.generateStartColorArray(lRows, oContext);
            List<String> aEndColors = TMUtils_ThemeVivid.generateEndColorArray(lRows, oContext);

            for (i = 0; i < lRows; i++) {

                LinearLayout outerButtonLayout = generateOuterButtonLayout(oContext);

                for (j = 0; j < lCols; j++) {

                    final Thread r = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            LinearLayout innerButtonLayout = generateInnerButtonLayout(oContext);
                            outerButtonLayout.addView(innerButtonLayout, j);

                            if (sourceElementIndex<originListSize){
                                final TMButton oButton = new TMButton(oContext);

                                if (callerActivity==1) { //testMenu
                                    setTestMenuButtonSettings(oButton, sourceElementIndex, Tests);
                                } else {
                                    if (callerActivity==2) { //testTypeMenu
                                        setTestTypeMenuButtonSettings(oButton, sourceElementIndex, TestTypes);
                                    }
                                }

                                if (strTheme.equals(testMe.theme_vivid)){
                                    oButton.fontSize = buttonFontSize;
                                    oButton.gradientStartColor = aStartColors.get(i);
                                    oButton.gradientEndColor = aEndColors.get(i);
                                }else{
                                    if (strTheme.equals(testMe.theme_purple)){
                                        oButton.gradientStartColor = testMe.btnStartColor_purple;
                                        oButton.gradientEndColor = testMe.btnEndColor_purple;
                                    }
                                }

                                configureButton(oButton, callerActivity);

                                oButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                                        Context oContext = v.getContext();
                                        TMButton oButton = (TMButton) v;

                                        int callerActivity = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString().split("@")[0]);
                                        String sourceId = String.valueOf(v.getTag().toString().split("@")[1]);

                                        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { //pressed
                                            setButtonPressed(oButton);
                                            TMSound.playButtonSound(oContext);
                                        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { //released
                                            setButtonReleased(oButton);
                                            startTargetActivity(callerActivity, sourceId, oContext);
                                        }

                                        return true;
                                    }
                                });
                                TMAppearance.doButtonAnimation(oContext, oButton, i);
                                innerButtonLayout.addView(oButton);
                                sourceElementIndex++;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    r.run();
                }
                llContainer.addView(outerButtonLayout);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there something about using `ListView` or `RecycleView` that you are opposed to? They can be highly flexible by using custom layouts.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply Barns52, no, of course I'm not opposed to ListView and in fact I'm investigating on how to implement a ListView because my buttons are generated programmatically.

Would you think I could use a ListView with dynamically generated buttons with no problem?

Comment: I like ListView (nostalgia? ;-) ) but RecyclerView was introduced as having a better performance compared to ListView e.g. when scrolling.

Comment: Again thanks for your reply @0X0nosugar but I ask the same question:
Is it possible to use a RecycleView with a List of dynamically generated buttons?

Comment: Yes. No. It's possible to use a RecyclerView with a data list containing the information so the RecyclerView Adapter can decide which View type to use for one data list entry. The various View types could be your different Button types. So all in all, yes :)

Comment: The important thing is that you *should not have* a List of Buttons somewhere but a List of ButtonInfo from which your Adapter can build the required Button, either in getView() with ListView (or GridView?) or by creating/ binding to a ViewHolder with RecyclerView. Both kinds of adapters support different ViewTypes, so all in all it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks again @0X0nosugar you are very kind. I'm doing some tests and have come to the conclusion that even though my method is not the most efficient possible one because I'm not using a RecyclerView the main problem is that reading all records (in my case are education tests and in this case we are talking of 50 tests with more or less 8 fields each) is the one who is consuming the 3 seconds so it seems that my only solution will be to paginate.

Maybe having a ListView with 50 views read from sqlite table is too much, what do u think?

Comment: Maybe you can use an AsyncTask to read the data and only refresh the ListView once the AsyncTask has finished its `doInBackground()` BTW creating the database on first run takes time, and it is recommended to do this in an AsyncTask by querying the database (any kind of query will do). This which will give you a Cursor, and then you'll have to really use the Cursor, e.g. call getCount(). Only then the database will be created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**0X0nosugar** is correct. A `RecycleView` will provide better performance, but many beginners have more difficulty implementing it and with only 50 buttons performance shouldn't really be an issue. And although I generally like to abide by the rule 'Use the best available solution' I think it is still appropriate to learn how to implement the `ListView`. So...

You will need to create a custom adapter:

```
public class MyListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyListData> {

    private static final String TAG = "MyListDataAdapter";


    public MyListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyListData> data) {
        super(context, 0, data);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        final MyListData data = getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.edit_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Add a TextView if you need one
        final TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        Button btnEditTicketHolder = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        btnEditTicketHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                long userId = data.getUserId();
                String fName = data.getFirstName();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId", userId);
                intent.putExtra("fName", fName);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        String name = data.getFirstName();
        tvName.setText(name);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Now you need your MyListData class to hold the data:

```
public class MyListData {

    // Add more as you need
    private long userId;
    private String firstName;

    public MyListData(){
    }


    public void setFirstName(String name){ this.firstName = name; }
    public void setUserId(long id){ this.userId = id; }

    public String getFirstName(){ return this.firstName; }
    public long getUserId(){ return this.userId; }
}
```

Your custom `ListView` layout could look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:text="With Whom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Edit"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:focusable="false"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity (eg. in the `onCreate()` method) where the `ListView` you will need to populate the data for the `ListView`. This should **not** be done on the UI Thread

```
    ArrayList<MyListData> arrayListData = new ArrayList<MyListData>();
    MyListDataAdapter adapter = new MyListDataAdapter(this, arrayListData);

    for (MyListData g : result) {
        adapter.add(g);
    }
    mLstMy.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also in the activity where the `ListView` is to be maintained set up some `onClick` event handlers if you need them:
(I find that one of the small advantages of the `ListView` is that the `onClick` event is easier it implement than in the `RecycleView`)

```
mMyLst = (ListView) findViewById(lstMy);
mMyLst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
        MyListData data = (MyListData) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        selectedName = data.getName();

        Intent intent = new Intent(ShowListDataActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

mMyLst.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        MyListData data = (MyistData) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        selectedName = data.getFirstName();

        selectedTicketPosition = i;
        // removeValue is my own method for removing an entry from the 
        // list MyListData and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        removeValue(i);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Barns52 for the great explanation on the ListView.

In the end I was able to implement a RecyclerView but the results where the same and come to discover that the delay was in the sqlite query.

I was able to optimize that query and consequently the screen render is now much faster.

I'll set your answer as correct due to your effort in all the ListView tutorial.